# How to force Ubuntu 14.04 to use HDMI only

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, gnome, hdmi

Ubuntu 14.04 + Gnome3 + Nvidia card

In both Nvidia's settings and Gnome's display settings, I've disabled the laptop screen, but when rebooting those changes do not stick and the main screen ends up being the laptop screen again.

Is it possible to force this change to stay so that HDMI becomes the main and only display after a reboot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the input of @kgiii, I have figured it out.

For starters, I am managing this computer remotely, so I had to do:

```
$ xrandr --display :0
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1200, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
LVDS-0 connected primary 1920x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 367mm x 230mm
   1920x1200      60.0*+
HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 820mm x 460mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   59.9     24.0     60.1     60.0  
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1440x480       60.1  
   1400x1050      60.0  
   1360x768       60.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1280x720       60.0     59.9  
   1024x768       75.0     70.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     72.2     60.3     56.2  
   720x480        59.9     60.1  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     59.9     59.9
```

From here, I was able to construct the xorg.conf file I needed based on the link @kgiii linked to:

```
Section "Monitor"
        Identifier      "laptop panel"
        Option  "ignore"        "true"
EndSection
Section "Monitor"
        Identifier      "big display"
EndSection
Section "Device"
        Identifier      "onboard"
        Option  "Monitor-LVDS-0" "laptop panel"
        Option  "Monitor-HDMI-0" "big display"
EndSection
```

There was no /etc/X11/xorg.conf file on my ubuntu install. Maybe that's normal, I'm not entirely sure. But it takes priority over any other Xorg config file as far as I understand.

This has effectively made the HDMI out my primary and only display.

If, like me, you're setting this up on a computer that is hard to reach directly, make sure it's connected to a network with an IP address you know about (I assign IPs based on mac address). You can remove the /etc/X11/xorg.conf file and restore normal functionality this way. It's a lot easier through SSH ;)

Answer (score 0):

This could be the nature of the beast - and might be something you can't change. The laptop, the hardware itself, may be responsible. I know that I have at least one laptop and if I reboot it then it pipes the display back to the laptop's display and not to the HDMI port until I press the button or select it within the OS itself. This behavior occurs if it is Linux, BSD, etc... I know of now way to alter this and I'm unable to find anything with a search engine that applies.

However...

What you can check is in your computer's setup. I've never seen such a critter but it's possible that you have such and that I've never looked well enough. It's often F2 or F12 during boot - sometimes it is ESC or whatnot. You'll then find a handy-dandy screen full of things you may not want to change so research accordingly. You'll be looking for something specifically aimed at your display settings - it would likely be on an "advanced" menu.

I do not know but I expect this is done for safety/ease reasons. When you press the FN and 'display' to change it to a new display it could not display or there could be a problem. Reverting to displaying on the screen during reboot may be a design choice. I can only confirm that I've seen this behavior and that it appears ubiquitous.

Actually, I take that back. I decided to try a couple of different search terms and it looks like this may be possible. Take a peek at this site.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13619/how-do-i-prevent-xorg-using-my-linux-laptops-display-panel

This appears to possible with the right search terms.